# interrogating Bank data - in OpenOffice 4.1.1

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I would be very grateful for any assistance with the following...

I have a worksheet of raw bank transaction data...I want to interrogate the data to display payments to the same source over the period to see how the payment values may have changed over time.

Columns:-

```
Date - Type - Description - Value - Balance
```

So if the 'Description' contains certain text eg 'BRITISH GAS' NB the string maybe in different positions in the 'Description'.

I want to display the Date - Type - Value for any matching row.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight your entire table, including the header row.  If it is very large, it may be easiest to type in the table range (e.g. A1:E5000) in the "name" box to the left of the formula bar.  When you hit 'Enter' after typing the range, the range will be highlighted.

On the menu bar, click on `Data`→`Filter`→`Standard Filter`.  In the dialog that comes up, select field name `Description` (the dropdown should be a list of your table column labels); condition `Contains`; and value `'BRITISH GAS' NB` (or whatever your search string is).

Click OK, and all non-matching rows will be hidden.  If you (while the table is highlighted) `Data`→`Filter`→`Remove Filter` all rows will be shown again.